# Can anyone explain this behaviour in yolo confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, confusion-matrix, yolov8

I have trained a model with yolov8 and only one class to detect objects in a video capture. After finishing my training I got this confusion matrix in the image.

I have tested the model and the model detects the objects correctly.

[image: confusion matrix]

Só why the confusion matrix gives me 100% in the background?